# how can pass the parametrized ActionResult value through ActionLink()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I cant understand how pass some data using `Actionlink()` to controller

In my project there have a controller name `ProductController` and a `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult ShowProduct(string location)
{
    return View(db.Products.Where(location=location).ToList());
}
```

and an `index.cshtml` view page in index there have-

```
<span id="spn-deliveryloccookies">@ViewBag.deliveryloccookies</span>
```

I am trying to pass `@ViewBag.deliveryloccookies` through

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cosmatics", "Cosmatics", "Product" new { location = @ViewBag.deliveryloccookies });
```

but data is not going.

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Cosmatics", "ShowProduct", "Product" new { location = @ViewBag.deliveryloccookies }, null);` (inspect the html your generating before and after the change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to store the  `@ViewBag.deliveryloccookies` into some variable.
So I have one idea.

```
var deliveryloccookiesdata= '@(ViewBag.deliveryloccookies)';
```

Now In ActionLink write code as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cosmatics", "Cosmatics", "Product" ,new{location=deliveryloccookiesdata});
```

Hope this works!

Comment: its good but it have to add null     
@Html.ActionLink("Cosmatics", "ShowProduct", "Product" new { location=deliveryloccookiesdata }, null);

Comment: Yes. Regret for that mistake. You can check syntax using Ctrl+ space